# Equivalent of C++'s typedefs/alias use in template programming

Tags: c#, templates, generics

I'm working on a C# project, and found myself trying to reproduce a common pattern in C++, but so far have been unable to. An example of what I'm trying to do (in C++):

```cpp
enum ProductItemTypes {
    Product,
    Family,
    SubFamily,
    Department
}; 

class ProductItem : PanelItem {
public:
    using item_type_t = ProductItemTypes;
    ...
};

enum PaymentItemTypes {
    Group,
    Valued,
    NotValued,
    Balance
};

class PaymentItem : PanelItem {
public:
    using item_type_t = PaymentItemTypes;
    ...
};
```

There are different classes that inherit from `PanelItem` and have their own `item_subtype_t`.
Then, classes that use `PanelItem`s, can know the corresponding item type and work generically.

Having some sort of similar ability in C# would help me avoid lots of repeated code, but I don't wan't to pass all the types (`ProductItem`, `ProductItemType`, and some more that I have excluded for simplicity) around all the time.

Comment: @Barry, I added [tag:C++] because you have to be able to read that source code.

Comment: Why not: template <typename item_type_t >
class Panel {
public:
    ....
};

Then
Panel<ProductItemTypes> foo;

Eventually you can define a type such as above.

Comment: @nosbor Yeah, the Panel part is not really important, the important part is the `item_subtype_t` in `ProductItem`, because different `PanelItem`s have different type definitions there

Comment: @nosbor I will edit the example to clarify this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly what your use case is here because you haven't provided an example of this:

> Then, classes that use `PanelItems`, can know the corresponding item type and work generically.

A class using `PanelItems` directly wouldn't be able to do this.  The only way around that would be if the class was a template class that took the type in directly (which I'm guessing is what you actually mean is happening):

```
template<class T>
class Foo
{
public:
    using item_type_t = typename T::item_type_T;
}
```

You're not going to be able to do this with C#.  While syntactically generics and templates look very similar they are two very different beasts.  C++ templates are compiled once for every different concrete type substitution that you make.  This is also what allows SFINAE to take place.  Basically every time the compiler sees a usage of a template, it substitutes in the type parameters and tries to recompile the class or method.

C#'s generics, on the other hand, are compiled exactly once and are agnostic to the type parameters.  This is the reason for the existence of generic constraints in C#: it allows you to give the compiler more knowledge about the kinds of types it's going to deal with.  It also means C# has no concept of SFINAE because there's no actual substitution done by the compiler.

My opinion is that your current approach is leaky.  Basically the different `item_type_t` types are implementation details of the derived classes and users of those classes must know what that type is in order to work with the type properly.  To me this is breaking encapsulation and C++ just provides a mechanism for you to get around this leakiness by hiding knowledge of the type from the programmer and only requiring the compiler to actually know it.

Without more details about exactly what you're trying to do it's difficult to give any suggestions about alternative approaches.  I'm fairly confident that there's an alternative design that'll cleanly deal with your problem, but right now this is a bit of an XY problem.

Comment: You are right, and you help me see I was too closed with my current idea, to open to a different and more suitable one. Thanks!

Comment: Also, thanks on the insight on generics vs templates!

Comment: @FedericoAllocati No problem, I work with a lot of developers transitioning from C++ to C# development and the generics vs. templates things is one of the sticking points.  Developing in C# is definitely different from C++ and it's common to want to try and bring patterns from one to the other, but that's almost always a mistake (and usually isn't possible as seen here).